# Web Scraping "Simple Site" with Selenium Hangs

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scraping a seemingly simple site that doesn't require a login, or any interaction with elements. However, when I use Selenium/requests/etc., the code just hangs. I've tried matching the headers to what I find using developer tools to no avail. I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

URL = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/blocks-records.xsl&url=/da/BlockTradeQuotes/V1/Block/BlockTrades?exchange=XCBT,XCME,XCEC,DUMX,XNYM&foi=FUT,OPT,SPD&assetClassId=8&tradeDate=06212021&sortCol=time&sortBy=desc&_=1624332329760'

agent = UserAgent()
userAgent = agent.random

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={userAgent}')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(URL)
```

The option arguments are recommended for getting chromedriver to run on Google Colab. I've tried it locally without them with the same result.

Comment: I believe you meant `--user-agent`, not `user-agent`.

Comment: Always add error message from the console as well to get an idea where you are getting stuck

Comment: Good looking out @TimRoberts, it's been fixed in the code. Thanks for the suggestion @Libin Thomas, unfortunately the code just hangs at the `driver.get(URL)` line, hence the missing error message.